# php mysqli stmnt check user login

Tags: php, session, mysqli, authentication

im writting a login system, user enter his email and password, script checks if its in database, then checks the password. My Problem, it checks only the first value, the others will be ignored. How do i complete loop through the database and then go to the else part if not successfull?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
$host  = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]);
$uri   = rtrim(dirname(htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])), "/\\");
require_once "db_daten_aktuell.php";

if (isset($_POST['email']) && ($_POST['passwort']))
    {
    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT vorname, email, password FROM gast"))
        {
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($vorname, $email, $password);
        while ($stmt->fetch())
            {
            if ($_POST['email'] == $email)
                {
                    if ($_POST['passwort'] == $password){
                        $_SESSION["name"] = $vorname;
                        $_SESSION["login"] = "ok";
                        $extra = "willkommen.php";

                    }

                }
              else
                {
                $extra = "start.php?f=1";
                }

            $stmt->close();
            }

        $mysqli->close();
        }
    }

header("Location: http://$host$uri/$extra");

?>
```

Comment: Mysql supports `WHERE` statement in queries. Read a manual.

Comment: Why don't you use ```where``` and compare at there only for require email id & password?

Comment: cause i don't know it yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change this part

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT vorname, email, password FROM gast"))
    {
    $stmt->execute();
```

to

`if ($stmt= $mysqli->prepare("SELECT vorname, email, password FROM gast WHERE email=? AND password=?"));
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $_POST['email'] ,$_POST['passwort']);
$stmt->execute();`

This way you can compare email and password first, and do other comparison later depending on the requirements. Please let me know if there is any other issues